# Open a form from modal form that opened from parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a form which makes lightbox effect.And after creating this lightbox form, i create another form.

```
//Execute from parent form
Form f = new Form();
f.ShowInTaskbar = false;
f.BackColor = Color.Black;
f.Size = this.Size;
f.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
f.Opacity = 0.6;
f.ShowDialog(); // Open Modal window
notificationSize nds = new notificationSize(); 
nds.Show(); // Open another form on Modal Dialog
```

After creating lightbox form, it doesn't show another form nds. Just showind the lightbox modal dialog.

how can i show the form on the modal form ?

Comment: nds.show will not run until showdialog has completed eg the form is closed. The cost of the dialog..

Comment: if you debug this, you would notice that while the debugger never reaches `notificationSize nds = new notificationSize(); 
nds.Show();` while the dialog is shown. So call the form before you show the dialog and set the `MdiParent` Property to your Form `f`, if you want it to be modal.

Comment: @Pulle How can i write this with mdi ? If you can write as answer ..

Comment: As an alternative to MDI, you can set `TopLevel` of "nds" to false, then add it to "f" as a Control, `f.Controls.Add(nds)`, and call `Show()` on it before calling `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yes, mdi didn't work as i expected. Could you please write as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display your "child" form by setting `TopLevel` to false:

```
Form f = new Form();
f.ShowInTaskbar = false;
f.BackColor = Color.Black;
f.Size = this.Size;
f.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
f.Opacity = 0.6;

notificationSize nds = new notificationSize();
nds.TopLevel = false;
nds.FormBorderStyle = ... // you may want to set this to none
nds.Dock = ... // you may want to set this to fill
f.Controls.Add(nds);
nds.Show(); // Open another form on Modal Dialog

f.ShowDialog(); // Open Modal window
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't quite get what the purpose of this is but this will do the trick:

```
        var f = new Form();
        f.IsMdiContainer = true;
        f.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        f.BackColor = Color.Black;
        f.Size = this.Size;
        f.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        f.Opacity = 0.6;
        var nds = new notificationSize();
        nds.Show();
        nds.MdiParent = f;
        f.ShowDialog(); // Open Modal window
```